# Rank-Nullity Theorem with Null Space and Column Space

Tags: matrices, vectors, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

I have

$$A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
2 & 2 \\
2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

I have found that $range(A) =
\left\{
\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 2\\ 2 \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 2\\ 2\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
\right\} $

and that $null(A^T) =
\left\{
\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ -\frac{3}{2}\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
\right\} $

I have been asked to state the rank and nullity theorem for $A$ and $A^T$. I know the rank and nullity theorem as rank($A$) + nullity($A$) = $n$ where A is an mxn matrix.

I know that nullity($A$) is the number of vectors present in the null space of matrix A, but I'm not too sure how to go on from there.

Can someone help? The solution states
dim(null($A^T$)) + dim(range($A$)) = 3

Yet I'm not sure how they arrived there

Comment: Just compute the Rank of both the matrices ( Null and Range) and show that it adds to 3.

Answer (score 1):

Since the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, the rank of $A$ is simply $2$. Since $A$ has only two columns the Rank-Nullity theorem for $A$ simply says that the nullity of $A$ is $0$, rank($A$) + nullity($A$) = n = 2. Since the rank of $A$ is two, then the dimension of the rowspace is two and in particular this means that the rows are linearly dependent. Thus $A^T$ has two linearly independent columns and so its rank is also $2$. But as it has three columns, the nullity must be $1$ to satisfy the Rank-Nullity theorem.

By simple Gaussian elimination, we get the following Gauss-Jordan forms for $A$ and $A^T$:
\begin{align*}GJ(A) = \begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&1\\
0&0
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align*} and
\begin{align*}
GJ(A) = \begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
From here it is easy to see the ranks and nullities.